# Extracting time intervals

Tags: r, time, intervals

I have a list of 1000 students and their test scores which are spread over a number of days. In the data set one column includes the time and date they sat the test in the ymd-hms format, e.g. "20170216-192809". I want to compare the mean scores of test results between students who took the test in the morning and those that took it in the afternoon and evening. How would I separate those that sat the tests between 12:00:00 - 23:59:59 and those who sat the test 00:00:00 - 11:59:59 so I can compare them?

Comment: Can you say a little bit about what you've tried so far? StackOverflow questions are expected to show some evidence of research effort (i.e. tell us how you've tried to solve your own problem before posting). (BTW, your current user name might not inspire much cooperation from dedicated R users ...)

Comment: Noted Ben Bolker thanks, I've managed to sus it out . I'll edit it to show what I did. And DooDoo is a good thing where I'm from.

Comment: please don't edit your question to include an answer; instead, post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyr)
d<-data.frame(time=c("20170216-192809","20170216-112530"))
d<-separate(d,time,into=c("date","time"),sep="-")
d$morning<-as.numeric(d$time)<120000
```

result gives you a column called morning which is TRUE for morning and FALSE for evening. To compare the means you can then do something like

```
mean(d[d$morning,"score"])
mean(d[!d$morning,"score"])
```

(you'll obviously need to have a "score" column for that...)